# Google places api for javascript autocomplete restrict to suggestions

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am using this api:

`google.maps.places.Autocomplete`

I need to be able to restrict my text field to only the results by the api, and not allow free text selection.

Here is my code:

```
var ac = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($('#txt').get(0));
ac.place_changed = function () {
    // TODO: add code to verify address if required
}
```

Is there some setting in the Autocomplete to do this...?

Comment: one solution would be select first option as default when user press enter key or user focus out from inputbox

Comment: this wont work if there is no result in autocomplete... it will still lead to the garbage text in the search box...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution by applying a few things.

First of all, the `form` tag needs `onsubmit` with `return`:

```
<form action="..." method="get" onsubmit="return formSubmitted(this);">
```

2nd, the autocomplete should set a variable (say `ac_var`) with acquired place data

```
ac.place_changed = function () {
    var pl = ac.getPlace();
    var addr = pl.address_components;
    ac_var = addr[0].long_name;
}
```

3rd, the function in javascript:

```
function formSubmitted(frm) {
    if ( frm.txt.value == '' || ac_var == '' )
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Some checks on the `addr[0].long_name` to check that it does exist or not should also be good.